# Authentication error "Access Denied" in AngularFire when using Internet Explorer 9

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase for simple email/password authentication. Logging in (using the AngularFire client) works fine on both Firefox and Chrome, but on IE9 I get an "Access Denied" error. At this point I have no security rules established, so by default all requests should go through. I've tried loosening the security settings on IE as well, but I still can't get through. Here's the Coffeescript I'm using to make the request, basically just the provided template from the AngularFire documentation:

```
.service 'loginService', ($firebaseAuth) ->
  ref = new Firebase "https://myapp.firebaseio.com"
  authObj = $firebaseAuth(ref)
  return {
    login: (user) ->
      authObj.$authWithPassword 
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      .then (authData)  ->
        console.log "Logged in as:", authData.uid
      .catch (error) ->
        console.error "Authentication failed:", error
    }
```

EDIT: I'm using Firebase v.2.2.2 and AngularFire v.1.0.0.

Comment: Please upgrade to 2.2.7, where at least one IE9 problem was fixed. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html If that doesn't solve it, please provide the exact and complete stack trace it comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Frank said in his comment above, this was just a bug in Firebase 2.2.2 that was fixed in 2.2.7.